# How can I dereference the elements of a Python DummyVecEnv OpenAI gym vector of enviroments?

Tags: python, object, openai-gym

I have created my vectorized enviroment with `test_env = DummyVecEnv( [lambda: myEnv(df)] )`, and defined a custom method `plot_stuff()` for the environment `myEnv`.

Now, I would like to do something similar to `test_env[0].plot_stuff()`, but this does not work:

> TypeError: 'DummyVecEnv' object is not subscriptable

I also tried using `map( lambda x: x.plot_stuff(), test_env )`, which got me this response:

> TypeError: 'DummyVecEnv' object is not iterable

My guess is that this is more of a newbie Python question than an OpenAI question, but I don't really know what to search for to find a solution to this problem.

Self-contained, (relatively) minimal, sufficient code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
from gym import spaces
from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

class someEnv(gym.Env):    
    def __init__( self):
        super(someEnv, self).__init__()
        self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([2, 2])
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box( low=0, high=1, shape=(1, 2), dtype=np.float64 )
    def plot_stuff(self):
        print("Hello")

test_env = DummyVecEnv( [lambda: someEnv()] )
test_env[0].plot_stuff()
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  In other words, the code you have given us isn't really enough to reproduce your issue/understand your problem.